How to estimate the integral $I=\int _{\frac{x}{2}}^{x} \frac{e^{t}}{t^{2}} \ dt = O(x^{-2} e^{x}),x \to \infty$
I want to show that $x\to \infty$ , we have $$\begin{align*}
I=\int _{\frac{x}{2}}^{x} \frac{e^{t}}{t^{2}} \ dt = O(x^{-2} e^{x})
\end{align*}$$ I know that when $x$ is large, $\frac{e^{t}}{t^{2}}$ is increasing, so we have $$\begin{align*}
I \leq \frac{e^{x}}{x^{2}} \cdot\left( x- \frac{x}{2} \right)= \frac{e^{x}}{2x}
\end{align*}$$ However, this only gives me $O(x^{-1} e^{x})$ . Is there a way to estimate it more precisely? Thanks!

$1/t^2$ and $e^t$ are of opposite monotonicity, so by the Integral Chebyshev inequality is
$$
 \int_{x/2}^x \frac{1}{t^2} e^t \, dt \le \frac {1}{x-x/2} \int_{x/2}^x \frac{dt}{t^2} \cdot \int_{x/2}^x e^t \, dt = \frac{2}{x^2} (e^x - e^{x/2})
\le \frac{2e^x}{x^2} \, .
$$

Notice that
$$
0\le I\le{1\over(x/2)^2}\int_{x/2}^xe^t\mathrm dt={4\over x^2}(e^x-e^{x/2})\le{4e^x\over x^2}.
$$

Performing the change of variables $t = (1 - s)x$ gives
$$
I = \frac{{{\rm e}^x }}{x}\int_0^{1/2} {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - sx} }}{{(1 - s)^2 }}{\rm d}s}  \le \frac{{{\rm e}^x }}{x}\int_0^{1/2} {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - sx} }}{{(1 - 1/2)^2 }}{\rm d}s} \\ = 4\frac{{{\rm e}^x }}{x}\int_0^{1/2} {{\rm e}^{ - sx} {\rm d}s}  \le 4\frac{{{\rm e}^x }}{x}\int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - sx} {\rm d}s}  = 4\frac{{{\rm e}^x }}{{x^2 }}.
$$
Alternatively, by L'Hôpital's rule,
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \frac{{I(x)}}{{x^{ - 2} {\rm e}^x }} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \frac{{x^{ - 2} {\rm e}^x  - (x/2)^{ - 2} {\rm e}^{x/2} }}{{x^{ - 2} {\rm e}^x  - 2x^{ - 3} {\rm e}^x }} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \frac{{1 - 4{\rm e}^{ - x/2} }}{{1 - 2x^{ - 1} }} = 1.
$$

If you are familiar with the expoential integral function, one integration by parts gives
$$\int\frac{e^{t}}{t^{2}} \, dt=(t-1)\, \text{Ei}(t)-e^t$$
$$I=\int _{\frac{x}{2}}^{x} \frac{e^{t}}{t^{2}} \, dt=\frac{2 e^{x/2}-e^x}{x}+\text{Ei}(x)-\text{Ei}\left(\frac{x}{2}
   \right)$$
When $y$ is large
$$\text{Ei}(y)=e^y\left(\frac 1 y +\frac 1 {y^2} +\frac 2 {y^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{y^4}\right)\right)$$ gives
$$I=\frac {e^x}{x^2}\left(1+\frac 2x -\frac{4 e^{-x/2} (x+4)}{x}+\cdots \right)$$ which is a very good approximation of $I$ (the error is less that $1.0$% if $x=26$ and less than $0.1$% if $x=78$) .

Consider the limit
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2e^{-x}I(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty}\int_{\frac{x}{2}}^x \frac{x^2e^{t-x}}{t^2}dt$$
Under the variable interchange $t\leftrightarrow xt$ we can rewrite the integral as
$$\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{x\left(e^{-(1-t)}\right)^x}{t^2}dt$$
which suggests using the substitution $u=\left(e^{-(1-t)}\right)^{x+1}$
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{x+1}\int_{e^{-\frac{x+1}{2}}}^1\frac{u^{\frac{1}{x+1}}}{\left(\log\left(u^{\frac{1}{x+1}}\right)+1\right)^2}du$$
$$\longrightarrow \int_0^1du= 1$$
by dominated convergence.
Therefore
$$\int_{\frac{x}{2}}^x\frac{e^t}{t^2}dt \sim 1\cdot\frac{e^x}{x^2}$$
as $x\to\infty$.
